# LocalNotification On Click Not Handler

Tags: iphone, xcode, localnotification

hello i am working on a application with `LocalNotifications`. I want to make a handler that when  the user tap on a notification in `NotificationBar` it will show him new Viewctontroler with Title and Descr that recieve from Notification.

```
 UILocalNotification *notif;

      for(int i=0 ; i<[idnoty count]; i++){
       notif=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
           if (notif == nil) return;


     notif.fireDate = [NSDate date];// Now here you can manage the fire time.
     notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
     [notif setHasAction:NO];
     notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
     notif.alertBody = [titlenoty objectAtIndex:i];
      notif.alertAction=[descrnoty objectAtIndex:i];
      notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = i+1;
      notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
  NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 2",@"Key 2", nil];
      notif.userInfo = infoDict;

               //apostolh gia na svisei ta push
   NSString *URLTest=[dict objectForKey:@"URL"];
   NSString *URL1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",URLTest,@"push.php?"];

   NSString *strURL1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@id=%@",URL1,[idnoty objectAtIndex:i]];


 NSData *dataURL1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL1]];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif ];

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this handling in

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Comment: And how i will know what Notification was taped. If i have n+1 notifications?

Comment: this will be called with the notification with which you have interacted in the "notification center bar/view"

Comment: this method will call n+1 times?

Comment: no.. only one time for the notification which invokes your app.